# Concat function with strings in XPath

Tags: xml, xpath, xpath-1.0

I am trying to get the complete address using XPath. I am new to XPath. This is what I have done so far:

```
<p class="adr" prop1="address">
<span class="street-address" name="streetname">2222 Warnar Ave</span>
<span class="country" name="country">USA, </span>
<span name="State">CA</span>
<span name="zip">1111</span>
</p>
```

My XPath

```
/p/span/text()
```

Result like an array:

```
Text='2222 Warnar Ave'
Text='USA,'
Text='CA'
Text='1111'
```

And I want the result as a complete one line address

```
2222 Warnar Ave USA, CA 1111
```

I have used `concat()` in my XPath but nothing is showing!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

### XPath 1.0 Solution

```
concat(/p/span[1],' ',/p/span[2],' ',/p/span[3],' ',/p/span[4])
```

Of course, instead of `/p/span[1]` you could specify `/p/span[@class='street-address']` etc.

### XPath 2.0 Solution

```
string-join(/p/span, ' ')
```